# Cape Verde: visa requirements and possibility of visa on arrival at airport?

Tags: visas, visas-on-arrival, cape-verde

I'm am European (French) and plan a holiday in Cape Verde (Cabo Verde).

Do I need to apply for a visa to stay there for 3 weeks?

If yes, do I have to get the visa before going there (ie. through ambassy) or can I simply get it when I arrive (at the airport)?

Comment: See also http://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/fr/conseils-aux-voyageurs/conseils-par-pays/cabo-verde-12223/ under “Entrée/Séjour”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. All visitors to Cape Verde require a visa. Cost €45. The visa allows you to stay for 90 days but you must enter the country within 180 days of visa issue.

You can either apply in advance through your local consulate / embassy or you can get one on arrival, but this process can take over 2 hours. It is recommended to do it in advance.

Comment: Add a couple relevant links and the answer becones perfect. :)